# How to echo data within a page template

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using short code to execute a video player in my page template but i also want to grab the URL from my custom theme options panel. This is the code I am trying and getting the error below. If i insert the video URL instead of my echo call then it works fine.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[KGVID]<?php echo $smof_data['home-page-video-url'];?>[/KGVID]"); ?>

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/muratgok/public_html/wp-content/themes/default/page - home.php on line 11
```

Comment: `do_shortcode("[KGVID]{$smof_data['home-page-video-url']}[/KGVID]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see for example [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode), do:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[KGVID]".$smof_data['home-page-video-url']."[/KGVID]"); ?>
```

yes you can do

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(
'[KGVID poster="muratgokmen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/…" width="1005" height="565"]'.$smof_data['home-page-video-url'].'[/KGVID]'
); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sudhir, can I extend it to include the thumbnail? This is what I was trying [KGVID poster="http://www.muratgokmen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/thumbnail-home.jpg" width="1005" height="565"]<?php echo $smof_data['home-page-video-url'];?>[/KGVID]

Comment: Thank you, I also linked the thumbnail so I ended up with this    <?php echo do_shortcode(
   '[KGVID poster='.$smof_data['home-page-thumbnail-url'].' width="1005" height="565"]'.$smof_data['home-page-video-url'].'[/KGVID]'
   ); ?>